# Datetime-local cannot choose the datetime show in to input

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datetime-format

I want to switch the current date picker (MuiPickersUtilsProvider) to another type of datepicker (normal datetime-local). But it doesn't work.

This is `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` datepicker coding (This is work)

```html
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
  <KeyboardDateTimePicker
    className="form-control"
    value={toDate}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setToDate(e);
      setStopDate(e);
    }}
    name="toDate"
    format={
      type === "Yearly"
        ? "DD MMM hh:mm a"
        : type === "Monthly"
          ? "Do hh:mm a"
          : type === "Weekly"
            ? "dddd hh:mm a"
            : type === "Daily"
              ? "hh:mm a"
              : SAASDateTimeFormat
    }
    minDate={fromDate}
  />
  {invalidMessage ? (
    <div className="fv-plugins-message-container">
      <div className="fv-help-block">{invalidMessage}</div>
    </div>
  ) : null}
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

The result for `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` is below"

[image: img1]

I want to switch the `normal datetime-local` date picker, but it doesn't work. Below is my coding:

```html
<Form.Control
    className="form-control"
    type="datetime-local"
    name="toDate"
    minDate={fromDate}
    value={toDate}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setToDate(e);
      setStopDate(e);
    }}
    format={
      type === "Yearly"
        ? "DD MMM hh:mm a"
        : type === "Monthly"
          ? "Do hh:mm a"
          : type === "Weekly"
            ? "dddd hh:mm a"
            : type === "Daily"
              ? "hh:mm a"
              : SAASDateTimeFormat
    }
    
    {invalidMessage ? (
    <div className="fv-plugins-message-container">
      <div className="fv-help-block">{invalidMessage}</div>
    </div>
  ) : null}
 />
```

The result for DateTime picker like this, this got problem because cannot choose the datetime show in the input, actually I want to show the result is `Sunday 02:40 PM`:

[image: input 2]

`toDate` value is `Sun Jul 31 2022 14:29:59 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`

`fromDate` value is `Sun Jul 31 2022 14:40:34 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`

`SAASDateTimeFormat` is `const SAASDateTimeFormat = "DD MMM yyyy hh:mm A"`

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.